# Why does my java code for reversing a linked list cause a cycle?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

so I for when I run this code on leetcode, it tells me Error - Found cycle in the ListNode, but I for the life of me can't figure out why. Please help, thanks in advance!

```
class Solution {
public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
    if (head.next == null || head == null) return head;
    
    ListNode curr = head.next;
    ListNode prev = head;
    ListNode next = head.next.next;
    
    while (curr != null) {
        curr.next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
        if (curr != null) next = curr.next;
    }
    
    return prev;
    
}
```

}

Comment: Did you walk through your code with a debugger yet?

Answer (score 0):

ok nevermind I know why, its because my head node needs to point to null, it was still pointing to the next element instead of null so there was a cycle between my first and second node

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have the following linked list:

```
A -> B -> C -> null
```

Initially, `prev = A`, `curr = B`, and `next = C`.

We'll trace out the first iteration of your loop:

`curr.next = prev` sets the link of `B` to `A`, so now our list is:

```
A -> B -> A -> …
```

The next two assignments set `prev` to `B` and `curr` to `A`.

`curr != null` is true. `next = curr.next` sets `next` to `B`.

We've lost track of the rest of the list (from `C`) entirely, and the cycle will never be resolved.